# Returning values from Gaussian fitting

Tags: python, plot, gaussian, valueerror, data-fitting

I'm trying to fit a Gaussian function to some data, but I want to return the 'center' and 'width' values and print them. However, the code returns a ValueError, and there is thus no plot. Removing 'center' and 'width' from the return line in the Gaussian function solves the problem, but I don't know how to get those values out from the fitting otherwise (and how to get the code to print them as output after fitting). Any advice?

The code & error:

````
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pathlib
import os
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit
 
#Data
data = np.loadtxt('....file.hst')
x = data[:,0]
y1 = data[:,1]
y2 = data[:,2]
 
n_gauss = 1
 
offset = 0
 
def gaussian(x, offset, area, center, width):
    y = area * np.exp(-(x - center)**2 / (2 * width**2)) + offset
    return y, center, width
 
def multi_gaussian(x, *gaussians):
    y = gaussians[0] * np.ones_like(x)
    n_gauss = (len(gaussians)-1) // 3
    for gauss in range(n_gauss):
        y += gaussian(x, offset, gaussians[3*gauss+1], gaussians[3*gauss+2],
                      gaussians[3*gauss+3])
    return y
     
#Plots:
plt.plot(x, y1, label="sync1")
plt.plot(x, y2, label="sync2")
popt, pcov = curve_fit(gaussian, x, y1, p0=[0, max(y1), 900, 120])
#popt, pcov = curve_fit(gaussian, x, y2, p0=[5000, max(y2), center, width])
#plt.plot(x, gaussian(y1, -2100, 3200, center, width),
#    lw=1, c='m', ls='--', label='Gaussian')
plt.plot(x, multi_gaussian(y1, -210, 270, 900, 120),
         lw=1, c='r', ls='--', label='multi-Gaussian')
#plt.plot(x, gaussian(y2, 0, 2250, 900, 120),
#    lw=1, c='r', ls='--', label='Gaussian')
#plt.xlim([850, 980])
#plt.ylim([30, 600])
plt.legend()
 
#Outputs
#print("Center: ", center)
#print("Width: ", width)```

The ValueError is:

    return func(xdata, *params) - ydata
 
ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (3,) (1201,),
````

Answer (score 1):

This happens because your gaussian function returns 3 values instead of one, so maybe try something like this instead:

```
def gaussian(x, offset, area, center, width):
  return area * np.exp(-(x - center)**2 / (2 * width**2)) + offset
```

Comment: Hey, this works in the sense that I don't get a ValueError, but I still want to print width and center somehow (see what I get for those values from the fitting). If they're not defined in return, how can I make the code give me those values?

Comment: maybe store them separately and then print them out ?
Because the curve_fit function expects a function that will just return a value :)